# Natbib Newblock Undefined Error with Informs3 Document Class

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am trying to submit an article to a Journal that uses the INFORMS3 document class. I used BibDesk to generate the BIB file and TexShop to compile the source file. Here is the TEX file, a minimum (non)-working example:

```
% LaTeX Article Template
\documentclass[moor]{informs3}
\usepackage{latexsym,amscd}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\stackMath

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}m{#1}<{$}}
\newlength{\mycolwd}                                         % array column width
\settowidth{\mycolwd}{$-\frac{3}{4}$}% "width" of $e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}|A|t$; largest element in array

%\smartqed
%\newcommand{\argmax}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmax}}

\setlength{\jot}{.2in}
% Set the beginning of a LaTeX document
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
%\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}

\RUNAUTHOR{X}
\RUNTITLE{X}
\TITLE{X}
\AUTHOR{X}
\ABSTRACT{
Sample
}
\KEYWORDS{
Sample
}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

There have been a number of alternative proofs of this result offered over the years; e.g. \cite{Spinetto:1974aa}, \cite{Charnes:1967aa}, and the methods employed have turned out to be of almost as much interest as the result itself. For example,  

\bibliographystyle{informs2014}
\bibliography{BalancedSetsELSArticleBibTex}{}

\end{document}
```

From within TexShop I can compile once with Latex and then twice with BibTex, no errors. However, when I then go to compile with Latex again, I get the following error:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation 'Spinetto:1974aa' on page 2 undefined on input line 43

Package natbib Warning: Citation 'Charnes:1967aa' on page 2 undefined on input line 43.

(./BibTexTest.bbl

./BibTexTest.bbl:1: LaTeX Error: \newblock undefined.

...

l.1 \begin{the bibliography}{2}
```

Here is the bbl file

```
\begin{thebibliography}{2}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\providecommand{\urlprefix}{URL }

\bibitem[{Charnes \protect\BIBand{} Kortanek(1967)}]{Charnes:1967aa}
Charnes A, Kortanek K (1967) On balanced sets, cores and linear programming.
  \emph{Cahiers du Centre d'Etudes de Recherche Operationelle} 9:32--43.

\bibitem[{Spinetto(1974)}]{Spinetto:1974aa}
Spinetto R (1974) The geometry of solution concepts for {\it n}-person
  cooperative games. \emph{Manage Sci} 20:1292--1299.

\end{thebibliography}
```

I am at my wit's end. I had no problem formatting the paper and bibliography with the ectaart or svjour3 or elsarticle classes, but I need it (of course) for INFORMS3 and I can't submit until I get this last piece done.

Any thoughts or pointers would be appreciated.

EDIT: I just came across a suggestion on a Google groups that magically fixed the issue (or at least allowed the generation of the References which is what I need to be able to submit): At the bottom of the TEX file, just before the \bibliographystyle, I added the line:

```
\newcommand{\newblock}{}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be `\def\newblock{\ }`, the Management Science template has the following defs:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}%
\def\bibfont{\small}%
\def\bibsep{\smallskipamount}%
\def\bibhang{24pt}%
\def\newblock{\ }%
\def\BIBand{and}%
```

Comment: Or `\newcommand{\newblock}{\ }` to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the benefit of future users:
I had a similar issue and found a 'backward slash' sign in my .bib entry which was not necessary.

Erroneous:

```
\newblock 2-way \FSI fails during first time step — {ANSYS} learning forum,
```

Corrected:

```
\newblock 2-way FSI fails during first time step — {ANSYS} learning forum,
```

Note that I have removed the 'backward slash' to correct it